# how does youtube lock direct links to the browser?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Recently youtube changed the way direct video download links work (found in url_encoded_fmt_stream_map), there is a signature now and links don't work unless the right signature is presented
the signature is there as a 'sig' argument so you can easy take it and construct the link and it will work, however ever since this signature appeared the link is also locked to the user's browser somehow

meaning if I probe "http://youtube.com/get_video_info" on the server side and construct the links with the signature and then print that as a link when the user clicks the link a black page will open, however if I try to download the video on the server side it will work. 
This means that the link is somehow locked and belongs to the user who opened "http://youtube.com/get_video_info"

The problem with this situation is that in order to stream the videos you have to first download them on your server

Does anyone know how are the links locked to specific user and is there a way around it?

The idea is for example - you get the link on the server side and then you feed it to some flash player, instead of using the chromeless player

here is a code example with php:

```
<?

$video_id = $_GET['id']; //youtube video id

// geting the video info
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$video_id);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);

// getting the links
$links = explode(',',$ytarr['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map']);

// formats you would like to use
$formats = array(35,34,6,5);

//loop trough the links to find the one you need 
foreach($links  as $link){
     parse_str($link, $args);

     if(in_array($args['itag'],$formats)){

          //right link found since the links are in hi-to-low quality order 
          //the match will be the one with highest quality
          $video_url = $args['url'];

          // add signature to the link
          if($args['sig']){
            $video_url .= '&signature='.$args['sig'];
          }

          /*
          * What follows is three ways of proceeding with the link, 
          * note they are not supposed to work all together but one at a time
          */

          //download the video and output to browser
          @readfile($video_url); // this works fine
          exit;

          //show video as link
          echo '<a href="'.$video_url.'">link for '.$args['itag'].'</a>'; //this won't work
          exit;

          //redirect to video
          header("Location: $video_url"); // this won't work
          exit;
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps it is using the session ID.

Comment: my guess is that the signature or part of the signature are probably the session id (coockies don't count, so it's not like the user won't have it and that's why will fail), once you open the link it checks if the seesion exists and is not expired, and identifies if it's the same user who created the link; the tricky part is what they use for identification and could you mask the user look like you server or more like it make the server look as the user

Comment: as of 2016 i can't get the signature to work even in the same browser/session.  does it still work for you?  https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py solves this, i'm trying to figure out how they're doing it.